# pg-promise update where in custom array

Tags: postgresql, pg-promise

How can the following postgresql query be written using the npm pg-promise package?

```
update schedule
set student_id = 'a1ef71bc6d02124977d4'
where teacher_id = '6b33092f503a3ddcc34' and (start_day_of_week, start_time) in (VALUES ('M', (cast('17:00:00' as time))), ('T', (cast('19:00:00' as time))));
```

I didn't see anything in the formatter namespace that can help accomplish this. https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/formatting.html

I cannot inject the 'cast' piece into the '17:00:00' value without it being considered part of the time string itself.

The first piece of the query is easy. It's the part after VALUES that i can't figure out.

First piece:

```
var query = `update schedule
set student_id = $1
where teacher_id = $2 and (start_day_of_week, start_time) in (VALUES $3)`;
```

var inserts = [studentId, teacherId, values];

I'm using this messiness right now for $3 (not working yet), but it completely bypasses all escaping/security built into pg-promise:

```
const buildPreparedParams = function(arr, colNames){
  let newArr = [];
  let rowNumber = 0
  arr.forEach((row) => {
  const rowVal = (rowNumber > 0 ? ', ' : '') + 
  `('${row.startDayOfWeek}', (cast('${row.startTime}' as time)))`;
    newArr.push(rowVal);
  });
  return newArr;
};
```

The structure I am trying to convert into this sql query is:

```
[{
  "startTime":"17:00:00",
  "startDayOfWeek":"U"
 },
 {
  "startTime":"16:00:00",
  "startDayOfWeek":"T"
}]
```

Comment: please show some effort.

Comment: Which part of this query got you stumbled? Show some code that you've tried.

Comment: I wanted to keep the question efficient. I can show work, but won't it just obscure the content?

Comment: @JacobMyers You could at least show the structure that you were trying to convert into values, so the answer would show how to do it correctly. Otherwise, no structure, no example, no good answer.

Comment: I hope this extra info helps. I would really appreciate any assistance!

Comment: @JacobMyers I have published the answer for you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [CSV Filter](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#csv-filter) for the last part: `IN (VALUES $3:csv)`.

And to make each item in the array format itself correctly, apply [Custom Type Formatting](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#custom-type-formatting):

```
const data = [{
    startTime: '17:00:00',
    startDayOfWeek: 'U'
  },
  {
    startTime: '16:00:00',
    startDayOfWeek: 'T'
  }];

const values = data.map(d => ({
    toPostgres: () => pgp.as.format('(${startDayOfWeek},(cast(${startTime} as time))', d),
    rawType: true
}));
```

Now passing in `values` for `$3:csv` will format your values correctly:

```
('U',(cast('17:00:00' as time)),('T',(cast('16:00:00' as time))
```